# How do I find out the php start flags <? or <?php

Tags: php

Is it possible to find out with php if the short start-flag `<?` does suffice in a script?

is there a ini-variable or do I need to program some function using output-buffering to see the results?

Comment: You can use `ini_get` to find out, but what are you going to do with that? In order to execute `ini_get` you already have to be inside PHP code, which means you are forced to use the long form to be safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`short_open_tag`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) in php.ini turns `<?` on/off. However, `<?=...?>` *always* works in recent PHP versions.

You can retrieve its value using `ini_get()` - but you cannot change it using `ini_set`. You *can* set it using a .htaccess containing `php_flag short_open_tag on` though.

So you should *never* use `<?` for PHP blocks but `<?php`. For expressions `<?=` is fine if you don't need to support ancient PHP versions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an ini variable, and it is called `short_open_tags`. So simply put `ini_get` with `sort_open_tags` as the parameter should return `true` if short tags is available on the server:

```
ini_get('short_open_tag')
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some double check now:

```
<?php
check_configuration(); // on a blank linux install check for some config flags
function check_configuration(){
    $test_short_open_tag=false;
    ?><? $test_short_open_tag=true; ?><?php
    if(!ini_get('short_open_tag') or !$test_short_open_tag){
       die( '<br>ERROR: please allow \'short_open_tag\' in php.ini or .htaccess to allow the use of "&lt;?"<br><br>'); 
    }
}
```